# Import Error on conda even directory exists

Tags: importerror, dlib, menpo

Environment info: `Anaconda`, `windows7x64`, `py3.5`

I setup a virtual env named as `menpo` to run `menpoproject`. For a long time I was using `load_dlib_frontal_face_detector` smoothly. After tinkering with a `pip-install dlib` command accidentally on virtualenv (I mean via Anaconda Prompt `menpo`) , I couldn't get my code working due to an "ImportError" `ImportError: cannot import name' load_dlib_frontal_face_detector'`. Code is like below:

```
import cv2
import menpo.io as mio
import menpodetect
```

Throws error at line 3.
There is this guy seems to had a similar issue.
https://github.com/menpo/menpodetect/issues/15

I did all the

```
conda remove dlib -y
pip uninstall dlib
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

stuff but still got the same error. Besides that;

Uninstalled Anaconda completely

Removed all Python folders wherever I found.

Installed Anaconda and setup a new menpo virtual env and still no luck. It seems like this dlib installation I made causing some issues. BTW, `conda list` produces `dlib 18.18 py35_2 menpo` and there is no `pip` line as mentioned in the link given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong alarm. Seems that I've named my py file as menpodetect which I shouldn't do. Problem solved.